# Adding custom button/link to AllItems.aspx

Tags: list, list-view

I wish to add a custom button/link to each row in my list's AllItems.aspx page.

I've selected 'Modify in SharePoint Designed (Advanced)' from List Tools.

I've added a SharePoint From Action Hyperlink which appears for each item in the list:

```
<a href="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__redirect={../notes/NewForm.aspx?ContactID={@ID}}')}">Form Action</a>
```

I was hoping {@ID} would render as the ItemId in the list, however this is not the case.

How do I get the ItemId so I can pass it through to NewForm.aspx?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use {$ItemId} to include the Item Id in the url.

```
<a href="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__redirect={../notes/NewForm.aspx?ContactID={$ItemId}}')}">Form Action</a>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it just shows {ItemID} on the QS. It seems I can't use those variables while I'm already inside a {

Comment: Instead I have done the following

<a href="../notes/NewForm.aspx?ContactID={$ItemID}">Form Action</a>

Comment: Updated the answer based on your findings.